# Remove the NO-REPLY from the workflow emails

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, email

I'm using workflows in Sharepoint 2010. I have a task that sends an email, but the sender is always NO-REPLY for the emails sent, how can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

The default address email used to send emails out is defined in the Central Administration:
under *System Settings* -> *Configure outgoing e-mail settings*.

Only a SharePoint Farm administrator can access this.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will see with the administrator and then I come back to tell you if it's ok